# how i can use compare attributes with parent child models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i have two model classes for parant child entities. each of them have date properties.

**the validation rule is**: child date must be less or equal to parent date in month and year. 
and i want to use compare attribute with parent property and child property. but i didn't succeed how to pass contextValidation parameter of isValid methode from parent to child.

please, how i can do this successfuly?

```
public class Parent 
{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public DateTime DateStartParent{get; set;}
   [CompareDate("DateStartParent")]
   public DateTime DateEndParent {get; set;}
   public vertual ICollection<Child> Children{get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
   public int Child{get; set;}
   [CompareChildDate("DateStartParent")]
   public DateTime DateChild {get; set;}
   public virtual Partent Parent{get; set;}
}

namespace BusinessEntities.CustomValidation
{
  public class CompareDate : ValidationAttribute
  {
    public string PropertyToCompar { get; set; }
    public Type ModelType { get; set; }

    public DateCompare(string comparedProperety):base(comparedProperety)
    {
        this.PropertyToCompar = comparedProperety;

    }

    public virtual bool ValidateDate(object value, DateTime comparedValue)
    {

        if (DateTime.Compare(comparedValue, (DateTime)value) < 0)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "La Date Début doit etre avant Date Fin";
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        } 

    public bool ValidateMoisEtAnnee(object value, DateTime comparedValue)
    {

        if (comparedValue.Year != ((DateTime)value).Year)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "une date de l'année  précédente n'est pas authorisée";
            return false;
        }

        else 
        {
            return comparedValue.Month > ((DateTime)value).Month;
        }


    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //define the entity to validdate
        var dra = (Parent)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        //define the property to validate with            
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.PropertyToCompar);
        //get the property value
        var comparedValue = (DateTime)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        if (!ValidateDate(value, comparedValue))
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        else if (dra.DateDebutDra == (DateTime)value && !ValidateMoisEtAnnee(value, comparedValue))
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        else if (dra.DateFinDra == (DateTime)value && ValidateMoisEtAnnee(value, comparedValue))
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        else
            return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

}



public class DateChildCompare: DateCompare
{
    private string _propertyToCompare;

    public DateDepenseCompare (string propertyToCompare):base(propertyToCompare)
    {
        this._propertyToCompare = propertyToCompare ;   
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //DateTime comparedValue = null;
        //definir the entity to validate with 
        var depense = validationContext.ObjectInstance as Child;
        //definir la proprité ou on applique la validation            
        var property =typeof(Parent).GetProperty(base.PropertyToCompar);
        //get the value of this property

        value = depense.DateDepense;
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);                                    

      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the use case if fairly limited, you probably don't need to add a separate validation attribute to the child. Something along these lines should work:

```
public class Parent
{
  [CompareChildDates]
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }
  public List<Child> Children { get; set; } 
}

public class Child
{
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class CompareChildDatesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
  {
    if (context.ObjectInstance is Parent parent 
      && value is DateTime parentTime
      && parent.Children.All(child => parentTime >= child.Time))
    {
      return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    return new ValidationResult("Validation Error Message");
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to validate create child form based on parent already created?